# Connectivity manager not working in xamarin.android fragment

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

In my app I would like to test if the device is connected to the internet and run some code correspondingly, and after searching the internet apparently the following code should work:

```
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
```

but it doesn't.

The debugger tells me that

> the name getActivity doesn't exist in the current context

What's wrong with this code? Here's the full fragment2.cs file:

```
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Webkit;
using Android.Net;
using Android.Widget;

using System;

namespace TabsApp.Fragments
{
    public class Fragment2 : Fragment
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your fragment here
        }

        public static Fragment2 NewInstance()
        {
            var frag2 = new Fragment2 { Arguments = new Bundle() };
            return frag2;
        }


        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            View v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment2, container, false);

            ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing here is the java code :

Xamarin works on c# so getters and setters are not methods but properties:

```
   ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)this.Activity.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.ConnectivityService);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.ActiveNetworkInfo;
```

Goodluck!

Comment: `Context.ConnectivityService` is underlined and gives the error: `member cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead`

Comment: Try it out now!?, All it did not have was a namespace and if it still doesn't work give it an activity context, if it works then mark it for some else who is looking for the same